# API key (CSA only) and Client Secret

Tags: secret-key

I’m hoping you can help me connect with the appropriate person to get some details on the LinkedIn Cross Site Awareness. There are two settings that we will need information for listed below. Any guidance you can help with is appreciated.

• LinkedIn API key (CSA only) – this is the LinkedIn Client ID from the LI Developers website

• LinkedIn Secret (CSA only) – this is the Client Secret for the Client Application

In case it’s needed, here is the text SuccessFactors provides: LinkedIn CSA allows recruiters who hold a LinkedIn-Recruiter license to access the LinkedIn profiles of candidates from within Recruiting. In order to user LinkedIn CSA you must: create a LinkedIn "key" (Client ID and Secret) on the LinkedIn Developers web-site (https://developers.linkedin.com/) and have the accounts for the recruiter licenses associated with the LI CSA key by LinkedIn.

Answer (score 0):

The API Key is used in several ways in CSA but the main use us as the username and the Secret as the password for the OAuth authentication for access to their REST APIs and JavaScript widgets.  A Linkedin member will need to own and maintain an "App" from within the developer site where the key and secret is generated.  A LI representative will link that App to the Recruiter Contract and there is a one-to-one relationship.  Anyone can add the developer options to their LI profile, the Recruiter contract requires $$$.

Keep in mind that the Api Key and the Contract Id are the ways LI restricts access and tracks usage for throttling and upselling.

Comment: The "App" language is somewhat confusing. I have the recruiter package and was told by Linked In that I needed to post my question here. Are they the only ones who can link the app to the recruiter contract? I guess that is what I'm ultimately trying to do! I'm not a developer, just the ATS admin trying to figure out the lingo!!!

Comment: They have to do the linking or at least say that that API key is valid to access the APIs with regard to the Contract.  Agreed that it is confusing.  The "app" represents the application/code that is accessing their APIs.  You can see from the tabs that they are trying to capture a lot of information that can apply to many types of access.  My end users have also seen some confusion on getting everything linked up.  If you like my answer, please +1 it, I need some points. :-)